# List<SelectListItem> Selected Value somehow set on both ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying set selected value to 2 List to show them on DropDownList in View.
I don't know why but StartDate also have EndDate selected value instead of the one I set it.

**Controler**

```cs
                List<SelectListItem> StartDate = new List<SelectListItem>();
                StartDate = lst;
                if (StartDate.Count > 0)
                {
                    StartDate[0].Selected = true;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Start Date: " + StartDate[0].Text);
                }
                ViewBag.ListStartDate = StartDate;

                //For EndDate, set "Select" for the last Entry
                List<SelectListItem> EndDate = new List<SelectListItem>();
                EndDate = lst; //lst is the default list without any select set to true
                if (EndDate.Count > 0)
                {
                    EndDate[EndDate.Count - 1].Selected = true;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("End Date: " + EndDate[EndDate.Count - 1].Text);
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[Finished End Info]");
                
                ViewBag.ListEndDate = EndDate;
```

**View**

```html
             End Date
             @Html.DropDownList("DateStartDropList", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListStartDate)

             Start Date
             @Html.DropDownList("DateEndDropList", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListEndDate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> StartDate = lst;
> ```

Please check the `lst`, I assume it should be a list of `SelectListItem`, right? If that is the case, the issue might relate that. Please refer the following sample:

If the `lst` is a list of `SelectListItem`, try to modify the code as below:

```
    StartDate = lst.Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Value = c.Value, Text = c.Text, Selected = c.Selected }).ToList();
```

The updated code like this:

```
        List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var newdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToString();
            lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = newdate, Text = newdate, Selected = false });
        };
        List<SelectListItem> StartDate = new List<SelectListItem>();
        StartDate = lst.Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Value = c.Value, Text = c.Text, Selected = c.Selected }).ToList();

        if (StartDate.Count > 0)
        {
            StartDate[0].Selected = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Start Date: " + StartDate[0].Text);
        }
        ViewBag.ListStartDate = StartDate;

        //For EndDate, set "Select" for the last Entry 
        List<SelectListItem> EndDate = new List<SelectListItem>();
        EndDate = lst.Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Value = c.Value, Text = c.Text, Selected = c.Selected }).ToList();  //lst is the default list without any select set to true
        if (EndDate.Count > 0)
        {
            EndDate[EndDate.Count - 1].Selected = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("End Date: " + EndDate[EndDate.Count - 1].Text);
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[Finished End Info]");

        ViewBag.ListEndDate = EndDate;
```

Besides, you could also Create a DateModel, and use it to store the DropDownList select items, code as below:

```
public class DateModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<DateModel> lst = new List<DateModel>();

    for(var i =0;i<10; i++)
    {
        var newdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToString();
        lst.Add(new DateModel() { Value = newdate, Text = newdate, IsSelected = false }); 
    };

    List<SelectListItem> StartDate = new List<SelectListItem>();
    StartDate = lst.Select(c=> new SelectListItem() { Value = c.Value, Text = c.Text, Selected = c.IsSelected }).ToList(); 
        
    if (StartDate.Count > 0)
    {
        StartDate[0].Selected = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Start Date: " + StartDate[0].Text);
    }
    ViewBag.ListStartDate = StartDate;

    //For EndDate, set "Select" for the last Entry 
    List<SelectListItem> EndDate = new List<SelectListItem>();
    EndDate = lst.Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Value = c.Value, Text = c.Text, Selected = c.IsSelected }).ToList();  //lst is the default list without any select set to true
    if (EndDate.Count > 0)
    {
        EndDate[EndDate.Count - 1].Selected = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("End Date: " + EndDate[EndDate.Count - 1].Text);
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[Finished End Info]");

    ViewBag.ListEndDate = EndDate;

    return View();
}
```

Then, the result as below:

[image]

Comment: `lst` is `SelectListItem`. I didn't know you have to Select from the list like that.
Thank you so much~